# Making a connect dots type of game based on touch in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx

I am making connect the dots type of game and I have to draw a line to where I touch on the screen, so I am using vector to store various points of my touch.

I used

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched())
{
    touchpos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
    System.out.println("touch at "+touchpos.x+" "+touchpos.y);

    if(circle1.contains(touchpos)) {
        ver[i]=touchpos;
        dline1=true;
        i++;
    }
```

So that the coordinates of my touchpos are updated in the vector and i draw a line to that point. But the above line of code `ver[i] = touchpos` doesnt seem to take the touch coordinates.

Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: print the Touchpos Array to see whats in it after a touch. Try printing x and y as you do at the `System.out.println("touch at "+touchpos.x+" "+touchpos.y);`

Comment: In case you use a `Camera` you should `Camera.unproject(Vector)` to get the coordinates in your game world, instead of screen coordinates.

Comment: I'd recommend using a `Stage` and an `InputProcessor` instead of using the `isTouched()` function.

Comment: use can also use touchdragged() in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here you are not creating a new object when you are assigning the value ver[i] = touchpos

so all your our referances **ver[0], ver[1] ... etc** else are same objects **touchpos**.

so what you can do is create all objects of array and then use ver[i].set(touchpos.x,touchpos.y)

also as  noone said you should use

```
camera.unproject(touchpos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(),0));
```

where touchpos is vector3 object